# Counting the word frequency in two list and output it in a dictionary

Tags: python

firstly thanks for clicking in.

I am just a beginner and have no background.

so I have two list of words, one is a checklist, another one is a sort of article,

what I need to do is use the words in the checklist to check the article, see how many time it repeated.

here is what I wrote:
[image]

my idea is use for loop to take one word in the first list and use it to compare with each word of the second list, and take another word in the first list and use it to compare with each word of the second list until the first list's words are all done.

what's the problem of my code?

could anyone just some suggestion for my code.

Comment: post your lists and expected input and output so we can look into it

Comment: in the `checkdict` should there be only the values that are in `poslist`

Comment: very first post and just checking it now, I will be doing what you guys suggested next time, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Some error handling fixes your code right up. You see, your code trys to add numbers to a key that doesn't exist. Then, if the word isn't in it, it creates that value at 1?

Try this instead:

```py
def check_lists(listA,listB):
  dictionary={}
  for x in listA:
    for y in listB
      if x == y:
        try:
          dictionary[x]+=1
        except KeyError:
          dictionary[x]=1
  return dictionary
```

This basically takes two lists and compares each value in listA against each value in listB. It then tries to add one to the key in the dictionary, and if the key doesn't exist (hence the `try` and `except` statements) creates a key and adds one.

Call it like this:

```py
check_dict=check_lists(joylist,poslist)
```

Comment: @Matiiss I have just put here what I use, and thats what I thought would be helpful. If you beleive you can post a better answer, then do so rather then complaining about others answers.

Comment: @Matiiss Thats fine. Not my fault or yours that this was upvoted. Democracy.

Comment: thanks for your response, your code is exactly what I am trying to do. 
just wanted to ask why when I dont have the try and except the code wont work? (didnt know this function before).

Comment: @HUGOLEUNG Your code won't work because it only checks whether the word is in the `poslist`, and not if it actually exists in the dictionary. The main problem with that is that you are trying to give value to a key that isn't there. Of course, this raises a `KeyError` because the key doesn't exist. What my code does is catch that error if it occurs, hence the `try` and `except` statement, and then creates that key in  the dictionary if the error is raised (i.e. it doesn't exist)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your post correctly, you have an article (or a long list of words, called `joylist` in your example) and you want to extract the word count for a subset of these (`poslist` in your case)?

Looking at your current solution, you'll get what you want with a little more work (@Agent Biscuit's solution), but this is not the most efficient solution because you'll be iterating over the entire keywords list every time, which you don't need to do. Since you're using a dictionary anyway, you might as well pre-load it:

```
# Create a new dictionary from the checklist with counts of 0
word_counts = {x: 0 for x in poslist}

# Iterate over all the words in the article
for word in joylist:

    # Check if the word is one we care about tracking. If it is then
    # increment the count associated with that word by one
    if word in word_counts:
        word_counts[word] += 1
```

If you don't want to use a list comprehension to create your dictionary then we can do this from an empty dictionary as well:

```
# Create the word-count dictionary from our list of keywords
word_counts = dict()
for word in poslist:
    word_counts[word] = 0

# Iterate over all the words in the article
for word in joylist:

    # Check if the word is one we care about tracking. If it is then
    # increment the count associated with that word by one
    if word in word_counts:
        word_counts[word] += 1
```

Finally, if you want to filter out counts of zero then you can do that too:

```
for k in list(word_counts.keys()):
    if word_counts[k] == 0:
        del word_counts[k]
```

Comment: I would say that the filtering could be done using a dictionary comprehension (more pythonic): `word_count = {k: v for k, v in word_count.items() if v > 0}`

Comment: @Matiiss Agreed but I thought to make the code more obvious to a beginning developer. List/dictionary comprehensions can be difficult to read if you're not used to them.

Comment: thanks for the considerate code, i will try it out this way later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the get method of the dict.

```
poslist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 't']
joylist = ['a', 'd', 'b', 'n', 'a', 'd', 'x', 'm']

c = {}

for j in joylist:
    if j in poslist:
        c[j] = c.get(j, 0) + 1
    else:
        c[j] = c.get(j, 0)

print(c)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 2, 'd': 0, 'b': 1, 'n': 0, 'x': 0, 'm': 0}
```

Comment: why do you even have the `else` block?

Comment: If item is not found we count it as zero.

Comment: but you don't need to add it all, you need to count only what is the `poslist`

Comment: Have you checked the posted image of what is poslist and joylist? Each item in joylist will be checked against the item in poslist.

Comment: but do you not see how the `else` block makes no sense, first of you will just have a dictionary full of keys that have a value of 0 intentionally but without reason, second it is pretty clear they want to get count of words that are both in the poslist and joylist, so the else bock makes no sense because it means that all the words will be added to the dictionary

Comment: As I see it, it is about counting what is in joylist as we can see in the image. The else block make sense because I am showing that if item in joylist is not found in poslist then we show the count as zero.

Comment: OP clearly state that they want to _use the words in the checklist to check the article, see how many time it repeated._ which implies that they would want to only count the words that are in the poslist. Also it doesn't make much sense logically to just have a 0 word count in the dictionary for words that don't even need to be there. Why then put a 0, then might as well count those, besides what if they wanted to check if any of the words in `poslist` weren't found in the `joylist`? how would they go about that? you can't just show all the items with count 0

Comment: `what I need to do is use the words in the checklist to check the article, see how many time it repeated.` This is about counting what is in joylist. `my idea is use for loop to take one word in the first list and use it to compare with each word of the second list, and take another word in the first list and use it to compare with each word of the second list until the first list's words are all done.` If an item in joylist is not found in poslist then that item must have zero count or zero repetition.

Comment: sorry for my bad explanation to cause this confusion, no a native speaker and not sure how to speak my logic out loud. but i am afraid ferdy is correct and presented my idea perfectly. thanks for both of the responses anyway!